# How to specify -1 label index for allennlp coref model

Tags: allennlp

I've adapted the allennlp [coref model](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/blob/4eb7c27d7fad00ac886ffdefc6c152909fa28f23/allennlp_models/coref/models/coref.py#L538) into my project. One thing I wasn't sure of was how to ensure that the label tensors are either a cluster index if the input span represents a valid mention, or -1 (otherwise the model doesn't correctly mask out the invalid spans).

I created a dataset reader that assigns a label field for each span. I used a dummy label for spans that aren't valid mentions (i.e. "O"). The issue is the token indexer assigns an arbitrary index to "O". It just happens that it's normally zero, it's certainly never -1. I worked around this by adding code in the coref module to mask out the dummy labels.

```
    self.invalid_span_index = self.vocab.get_token_index(invalid_span_label, label_namespace)

    if span_labels is not None:
        valid_span_labels_mask = span_labels != self.invalid_span_index 
        span_labels = util.replace_masked_values(
            span_labels, valid_span_labels_mask, -1
        )
```

This works ok, but it should really be done by the token indexer or earlier, so I guess my question is how do you ensure that the token indexer produces specific indexes for certain special labels? Particularly in this case where the model has a requirement that the index is -1

Perhaps I should use `skip_indexing=True` in the dataloader and index the clusters myself. The issue I have with this approach is I'm using a `MultiTaskDataLoader`. It should work for now as I'm using `HomogeneousRoundRobinScheduler` so the model shouldn't see spans from more than one document at a time so at this stage at least I can probably get away with not using a vocabulary. But it doesn't feel like the proper way to do this?

Comment: It's not uncommon to use `skip_indexing=True` for labels. I would recommend that. Why is it a problem to do that with multitask training? Is there something in `MultitaskDataLoader` that we should fix?

Comment: Because then I'd have to maintain my own str2id from text labels to indexes right? I have NER span labels which are shared across multiple documents which also include a -1 label for spans which aren't mentions. I'm not sure how to use `skip_indexing=True` in this case as I then cannot predict the actual text labels later if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: PS It's not so much multi-task where the friction is, it's span based modelling where you enumerate and then prune spans, and then pass on to a scorer. These models seem to require an 'invalid span' label.

Comment: If you have only one set of tags that you care about, maintaining a string-to-id mapping is trivial. It could just be a dict in a dataset reader.

I assume then that you have multiple different sets of potential labels, and you need them combined intelligently into one vocabulary namespace?

Comment: Doesn't each dataset/task get it's own reader though (for a `MultiTaskDataLoader`)? I have one set of tags but multiple documents (each of which I consider a task) because I need to ensure the model only gets a batch consisting of sentences from a single document at a time. So I need to index labels for a single vocabulary namespace but instances will be read by different readers I think.

Comment: If all the tasks use the same dataset reader, you can use `skip_indexing`, and put a static dictionary in the dataset reader, mapping tag names to integers:

```
my_tags = ["B", "I", "O"]
tag_to_index = {tag: index for index, tag in enumerate(my_tags)}
```

Comment: That formatting went all over the place, but I hope it's clear what I mean.

Comment: Yeah I was considering a static dict, thanks.